# VBA Apply Filter and Formatting to Select Worksheet

Tags: arrays, loops, conditional-formatting

I have been trying to fix the coding below. I first wanted to only highlighted duplicate values in Column D. Second, in Column Q and Column R, I would like to filter all data out and show only the blank cells. This is a large Yearly report that is updated weekly.
When I ran the Macro, it did the first 2 states and then it gave a debug error. Also, some of the sheets already have the conditional formatting on Column D. I think this is causing part of the issue. When this coding is done I will add more worksheet names to the coding. Thank you for any guidance on this!

```
Sub Test()
Dim WY As Workbook
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim Table As ListObject

For Each Ws In Worksheets(Array("AR", "CA", "FL", "MI", "TX"))
    Set Table = Ws.ListObjects(1)

With Table
    Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
    .Color = -16383844
    .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 13551615
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
Range("R1").Select
.AutoFilter.Range.AutoFilter .ListColumns("Respond Yes").Index, "="
.AutoFilter.Range.AutoFilter .ListColumns("Respond No").Index, "="
End With
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What "debugging error" did it give?

Comment: I get the [Run-time error '1004' AutoFilter method of Range class field]. The 3rd state gets the blanks removed but the code stops at highlighting the duplicates.